# How to Call oidc-client signinSilentCallback in a ReactJs Component

Tags: node.js, npm-install, webpack-2, identityserver3, oidc-client-js

I need to implement the **`Slient-Renew`** Token using **`oidc-client`** or **`redux-oidc`** - **`npm node module`**.

I'm using **Identity Server Version 3.0** and **Javascript ReactJs Client UI Application (Webpack Version 2)**.

I'm having a simple Javascript application download from github, the Slient Renew HTML file is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Silent Renew</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./oidc-client.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Oidc.UserManager().signinSilentCallback();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I created a Route

```
<Route exact path='/SilentRenew' component={SilentRenew} />
```

The Component code is

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import UserManager from 'oidc-client';

/**
 * <p>.</p>
 * @extends Component
 */
class SilentRenew extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    alert('Hai');
    const userManager = UserManager();
    userManager.signinSilentCallback();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>Silent Renew</div>
    );
  }
}

export default SilentRenew;
```

I'm getting error

[image]

Kindly assist me how to call the **`signinSilentCallback`** method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the code

```js
const userManager = UserManager();
userManager.signinSilentCallback();
```

inside `componentDidMount()` instead of `constructor()`.

Check React Component lifecycle methods...

Comment: Hi @vlad Can I get a complete react code sample for oidc-client (OAuth2 + OIDC) in react, without typescript sample. Is there any proper link? I saw many but those are not much clear, only pieces of code are available. I like to see a complete example